# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity

Tags: java, rest, jboss, resteasy

**What i am doing**

Previosly i am using Jercey Client but Jercey don't have mechanism called *Retry* I have to use RestEasy client so i have added below dependency in my pom.xml file

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JAXB support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-atom-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-links</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
             <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Java code I have written

```
 ResteasyClient client;
   client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
   ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(usersRequest.getUrl());
   Response  response = null;
   if(null != usersRequest.getXmlObject()){
   response =  target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).post(Entity.entity(usersRequest.getXmlObject(),MediaType.TEXT_XML));

   }else{
   response =  target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get();
           }
   output = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

But I am ending with below error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>     at
>   com.alu.ipprd.mdf.soa.portal.integration.restapi.RestAPIUsersFacade.getAuthorizationUserRole(RestAPIUsersFacade.java:212)
>   [mdf-portal-integration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]  at
>   com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.business.aaa.UsersWorkOrder.processBusinessLogic(UsersWorkOrder.java:57)
>   [mdf-portal-business-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]     at
>   com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.business.aaa.UsersWorkOrder.processBusinessLogic(UsersWorkOrder.java:1)
>   [mdf-portal-business-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]     at
>   com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.common.business.BaseWorkOrder.submitWorkOrder(BaseWorkOrder.java:75)
>   [mdf-portal-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]   at
>   com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.bean.LoginBean.doLogin(LoginBean.java:907)
>   [classes:]    at
>   com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.bean.LoginBean.verifyLogged(LoginBean.java:1150)
>   [classes:]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2464)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]  at
>   javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]  at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2168)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2116)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:288)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:246)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:108)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

I also checked the jar  `jaxrs-api-3.0.8.Final.jar` which contain this class and method also in present even then its not going to resolve. Can any one tell me what i am doing wrong?

**EDIT 1:-**
I restrict Jboss to use resteasy jar by adding following entry in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>

        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-atom-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-yaml-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
            <module name="org.javassist" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javaee.api">
                <imports>
                    <exclude path="org/apache/xml/security/**" />
                </imports>
            </module>

            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider" />
            <module name="org.codehaus.jettison" /> 
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Looks like you still have the same problem. `Response` is a JAX-RS class that is used for both server side and client side. In JAX-RS 1.x there is no standard client side support. With JAX-RS 2.x that's when a client API was added, and methods like `readEntity` were added to the `Response` object to support client calls. So like I said, you are still having the same problem with old classes being loaded

Comment: If you can't get it working, I don't see why you can't just use the 2.3.x version of the RESTeasy library, since you are only need the client. Other application that disabled the old version to upgrade will not affect your application that still uses the old version

Comment: You can see the docs for [2.3.x client api](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.7.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html). Then just use the older version of the resteasy-client

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for your suggestion server is using 3.0.8 version

Comment: From what I understand from out conversation yesterday is that the other team that is working on the REST application (which is a different application) is only excluding the old module (like you are doing) not replacing. So the REST application can use the newer version, and your application , which only needs the client can use the old version still. Different applications have different class loaders.

Comment: But anyway, what happens if you also exclude the `javax.ws.rs.api` module?

Comment: @peeskillet Let me try that also

Comment: @peeskillet Even i excluded i got same exception which i posted in question

Comment: @peeskillet Its working

Comment: How did you get it to work?

Comment: @peeskillet I have added that in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any how this [RESTEasy Client + NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139097/resteasy-client-nosuchmethoderror) will help to resolve the issue.As i am using Jboss7.1.0.final server when i unzip `resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final-all` it have `resteasy-jboss-modules-3.0.8.Final` and `resteasy-jboss-modules-3.0.8.Final` come up with three folder `com`,`javax`,`org` these 3 folder we have to copy and paste to `jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\modules`

I am copying only `resteasy-jboss-modules-3.0.8.Final\org\jboss\resteasy` to Jboss server so it was failing.

Comment: @peeskillet Right now i done this in locally .In Production server we are using Jboss EAP. Frankly telling Right now i am not sure What i will do there.

Answer (score 1):

This problems are thrown cause of different version of Resteasy Client implementation between your app and Jboss.

Please see [RESTEasy Client + NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139097/resteasy-client-nosuchmethoderror)